# Any recent updates to OpenGL?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, opengl

I do engineering work in VariCAD.  It offers three display options per object: "Shaded", "Transparent", and "Wireframe".

This has worked extremely well until recently.  Now, when I start the program, I get an error stating that it cannot "initialize OpenGL extensions" and that it's reverting to "OpenGL 1.1".

I contacted their tech support and at the same time uninstalled and re-installed successively older versions, thinking this to be a VariCAD problem.  Now that I'm seeing the same behavior on older versions of VariCAD, and given this problem only recently started happening, I'm beginning to wonder if it's something in the guts/kernel of Ubuntu that got updated and broke the ability to start OpenGL.

Upshot is, we have no "Transparent" capabilities now, which worked fine before.

Output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`

```
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Dell 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

    01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104GLM [Quadro K3000M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell GK104GLM [Quadro K3000M]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.2 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.2.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.20
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 19.2.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 19.2.8
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Comment: How is this Ubuntu related?

Comment: Read the whole thing and you'll see.

Comment: So what is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: This is Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: All looks good. Are you using Nvidia or Intel adapter? What does `prime-select query` show?

Comment: `nvidia` is what it shows.   More specifically (from Software & Update -> Additional Drivers), nvidia-driver-390

Comment: OK, then post output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` to your question.

Comment: This really looks like a bug. I checked my system and it doesn't show the extensions version any more for some reason. The same as yours.

Comment: In your case the renderer is wrong. It should be `OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation`

Comment: Thank you.  To clarify, do you mean a bug in VariCAD's startup of OpenGL (which was working) or in a recent kernel update?  This will help me work with the company on any action they need to take.

Comment: I am writing an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to upgrade the driver.

Run in a terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-418
sudo apt upgrade
```

Most likely this will fix the issue on the 5.3 kernel.

Comment: Trying it.  (Sidenote: the `sudo apt update` is no longer required.)

Comment: I know that it is included into the `add-apt-repository` script, but I still include it in case it is not there for some reason.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  This resolved the issue.